Change shortcut to switch tab in nautilus/files?
In nautilus/files, I would like to change my shortcut to change tabs:
Switch to Previous Tab: Ctrl+Shift+Tab
Switch to Next Tab: Ctrl+Tab

Just like in every browser.
How can i do it?
thanks
Ubuntu 22.04.4

Unfortunately, nautilus does not offer any possibility to change keyboard bindings apart from editing source code and recompiling. However, there is hope. After many years of feature requests, subsequent versions of Files, i.e., the one you find in the current long term release of Ubuntu, 24.04, support Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab for moving forward and backwards through tabs. The old Ctrl+PagDn/PgUp also continue to work.
